# same project with login and without login based on the url?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, asp.net-membership, login-control

I would like to set up my web project with login.aspx and without based on the url entered.

lets say if someone access www.mywebsite.com/A - can make a search without login

```
                             but if accesses on www.mywebsite.com/B  will be with login.
```

I work with the session as websiteID but that causes problem. websiteIDs are running into each other.

Reason of why I do that solution is B way is not public. it is to be used for some certain people other one is public.

Is this kind of bad implimentation ? should I split into 2 different web project? I didnt do that because everything is same but only

difference is the search results. therefore it is cumbersome to do 2 uploads and maintaine 2 projects.

web.config is another problem because i can't do asp.net membership provider solution while it affects also solution A.

what would be your suggestion?

Ps; I heard securing only specific directory in web.config. how can I do that? can this help?

EDIT: Both have same step aspx pages. after I login I get redirected to the default page which is used by solution A as well. only difference is querystring parameter. that's why securing default.aspx if it is the first search page for both, will affect both. Securing path in web.config won't work unless if it is possible to secure with query string parameters? Am I wrong?

thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following: Deploy two different solution configurations of your current application into two differences IIS sites. You can maintain the same codebase, but you use different settings in different web.config.

You could create a "preview" solution configuration. In the web.preview.config you would add forms authentication code.

You can find more details here: http://www.tomot.de/en-us/article/5/asp.net/how-to-use-web.config-transforms-to-replace-appsettings-and-connectionstrings

Comment: well at the moment, I did kind of what you say. but probably with a quite awkward way. because I keep 2 web.config file (web.config and web.config2) and depending on which one I publish, I switch the name to be web.config. Thanks for the link. I am reading it.

Comment: I have just finished reading the article. thats pretty nice to learn but I am not sure if it can help me while I am not looking for test/prod environment set up differences but rather I want to run 2 web.config for 2 project (1 physical project indeed like I explained above)

Comment: I think you haven't understood that web.config transforms are not limited to the samples I used in my article. It's possible to change the nearly everthing automatically in the web.config. It seems to me, that  the only difference between your two published sites is the publish location and the web.config? If I'm correct in that assumption, using web.config transforms is the way to go

Comment: You understood me correctly- 2 published website 2 config (1publish location would be great if possible but i am fine with 2 publish as well) t hank you very much. I am going to try your solution. One question, is it possible only with website publish or copy website isnt any difference?

Comment: I've only seen it with website publish

Answer (score 0):

The archiecture you are using is quite correct , you need not to create two different applications.
Regarding for the pages which require signing in, Google for the term

'location path in web.config' ,
 you will get the complete solution for authentication and authorization of webpages

Edit-> I can't post the solution for authentication and authorization of webpages as it is too large, hope doing R&D by yourself will help u learn more and find appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<location path="A.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
      </authentication> 
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

this might help

Comment: actually, you got me wrong or I probably explained not sufficient. they have same step aspx pages. after I login I get redirected to the default page which is used by solution A as well. only difference is querystring parameter. that's why securing A.aspx if it is the first search page for both, will affect both. am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this in code behind. Just check the value websiteID (session variable) during the page load of default.aspx and change the search parameters accordingly.
Don't forget to give default value to websiteID in Session_start of Global.asax, so that you can easily check whether its modified by login.